Setting Chartjs Global Defaults for Individual Axes
According to the documentation, Chartjs (v4) grid styling is controlled using the options.scales[scaleId].grid namespace. I can control the styling globally of select elements using statements like:
Chart.defaults.scale.grid.display = true;
Chart.defaults.scale.grid.lineWidth = 5;

However, I can not seem to find the syntax for controlling defaults for individual axes using the [scaleId] portion of the above namespace. I have tried the following to no avail:
Chart.defaults.scales.x.grid.display = true;
Chart.defaults.scales['x'].grid.display = true;

What is the proper syntax to set defaults for the axes individually?
TLDR; I am setting global display properties in a separate file and importing those settings into each chart (I have over 20 charts) within a Vue 3 project.
chartDefaults.js
// Set project defaults

import Chart from "chart.js/auto"

// general
Chart.defaults.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.maintainAspectRatio = false;

// animations
Chart.defaults.animation.duration = 2000;
Chart.defaults.animation.easing = 'easeInOutQuart';

...

I've inspected the Chart.defaults object, but I don't see references to the individual axes within the defaults object.

UPDATE: I've found a construction my IDE will accept, but it doesn't seem to affect the charts.
Chart.defaults.scales.linear.axis.x = {
  grid: {
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
    display: true,
  }
};

Solution
In order to show the proper formatted solution for my question, I am attaching it here. The solution was provided by @kikon below.
if(!Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid){
   Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid = {};
}
Chart.defaults.scales.category.grid.color = 'red'; // x-axis


I found this question -- which is in the neighborhood -- but it doesn't get to a solution for my specific question.

The answer to this question is for a prior version of Chartjs and is no longer valid.

There's no difference in the definition of axes between their roles as x, y or r. You may set the defaults by their type, i.e., linear, category, time, etc.
The default state of most plot types is that x axis is of type "category" and y axis of type "linear". If that's the case for all of your charts, then you may use that to set the defaults:
if(!Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border){
   Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border = {};
}
Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border.color = 'blue'; // y-axis

if(!Chart.defaults.scales.category.border){
   Chart.defaults.scales.category.border = {};
}
Chart.defaults.scales.category.border.color = 'red'; // x-axis

However, if you are about to use different-than-default the axes types, like using linear axes for both x and y, you may use the fact that the options you need are scriptable,
so you may set their default values to functions that interrogate the role of the scale at run-time, through the .axis property (its value may be x, y or r):
if(!Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border){
   Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border = {};
}
Chart.defaults.scales.linear.border.color = function({scale}){
   if(scale.axis === 'x'){
      return 'red'
   }
   if(scale.axis === 'y'){
      return 'blue'
   }
};

Here's a more elaborate example:


for(axisType of ['linear', 'category']){
    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].border = Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].border ?? {};
    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].border.color = function({scale}){
        if(scale.axis === 'x'){
            return 'red'
        }
        if(scale.axis === 'y'){
            return 'blue'
        }
    }

    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid = Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid ?? {};

    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'
    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid.display = function({scale}){
        if(scale.axis === 'x'){
            return true
        }
        if(scale.axis === 'y'){
            return false
        }
    }
    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid.tickColor = function({scale}){
        if(scale.axis === 'x'){
            return 'red';
        }
        if(scale.axis === 'y'){
            return 'blue';
        }
    }

    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].ticks = Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].ticks ?? {};
    Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].ticks.color = function({scale}){
        if(scale.axis === 'x'){
            return 'rgb(128, 0, 0)';
        }
        if(scale.axis === 'y'){
            return 'rgb(0, 0, 192)';
        }
    }
}
const data = {
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Some data',
            showLine: true,
            pointRadius: 2,
            data:
                [ {x: 8.25257, y: 8.25257}, {x: 9.30005, y: 12.30005}, {x: 9.90518, y: 9.90518} ],
        }
    ]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales:{
            x:{
                type: 'linear'
            },
        }
    },
};

new Chart(document.querySelector('#chart1'), config);
<div style="min-height:400px">
    <canvas id="chart1"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>




Thank you for taking the time to write such a thorough and thoughtful reply. This approach changes the color of the x- or y-axis, whereas I'm looking to change the color of the grid lines (in my case the vertical lines emanating from the x-axis). I will see if I can adapt this example to the grid lines.

It was easily adaptable. Works like a charm. Cheers! I will add as an addendum to my question to allow for proper formatting.

The color of the grid lines is set in the code line Chart.defaults.scales[axisType].grid.color = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' Since only one of the grid lines is visible this option can be static. If you want both axes grid lines visible, you may set this option to a function too.

Looking deeper into your revised answer, I like the way you handle any potential y-axis instances. Nice.

Following up on answer by kikon,
I am using chartJS with Laravel 11 and I am configuring some global settings in the app.js file. I discovered that the code in the answer by kikon was not working for me. By playing around I ended up with the following code which seemed to work for me.
/* resources\js\app.js */

Chart.defaults.scale.grid.color = '#fff3';
Chart.defaults.scale.grid.display = function ({ scale }) {
    if (scale.axis === 'x') {
        return false
    }
    if (scale.axis === 'y') {
        return true
    }
}

Chart.defaults.scale.border.color = function ({ scale }) {
    if (scale.axis === 'x') {
        return 'white'
    }
    if (scale.axis === 'y') {
        return 'transparent'
    }
}

Chart.defaults.scale.grid.tickColor = 'transparent';

I don't know if it is Laravel or there has been changes in chartJS itself since the previous answer, but I hope this will be useful to someone.
